# custom post type template

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type "recipes". I created it using the custom post type UI plug in.

the name is ic_recipes, the label is Recipes and the rewrite slug is recipes

the url is formed as mysite.com/recipes/lentil-soup/

Here is the question...

I wanted to create the template file for this custom posts types to use..

but no matter what i tried, wordpress ended up using the single.php.

I've supplied the following files to the twentyten theme folder;

```
recipes.php
ic_recipes.php
archive-recipes.php
and finally archive-ic_recipes.php
```

none kicked in. single.php was the one every single time.

I checked the codex. codex has the the following to say ( I copy/pasted for you at the bottom of this question) about the the template naming!

Please tell me what is it that I'm missing..

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display

Custom Post Types display

```
archive-{post_type}.php - If the post type were product, WordPress would look for archive-product.php.
archive.php
index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

archive-xxx.php is for archives. You want to use single-xxx.php as an alternate to single.php.

Comment: I tried both the single-recipes.php and the single-ic_recipes.php. still, single.php runs! by the way, the XXX part, is that supposed to be custom post type name, rewrite slug or the label?

Comment: @AverageJoe single-recipe.php is the right name. You probably are viewing the cached copy, try clearing the cache. XXX is the post slug.

Comment: What if my post-type's instances are only meant to be rendered as a carousel on particular custom page ? (No url for archive, no direct access via url) only gathered programmatically in a `$loop = new WP_Query(array(…));while ( $loop->have_posts() )… get_template_part( ??, 'my_post_type');`